# collectionView footer not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I've checked the `section footer` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: collectionViewAttributesInspector]

I've also implemented the `dataSource` method:

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
      var header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DetailHeader
      if header == nil {
        header = DetailHeader()
      }
      return header!
    } else {
      println("footer")
      var footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView
      return footer
    }

  }
```

I was able to display my header, but my footer is never displayed. The `println` never triggers either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Screen shot from storyboard:
   [image]

2.My code:

```
import UIKit

class BaseCVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cvcCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        return cell;
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Int(2)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 20)
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath)

            return header

        } else {
            print("footer")
            let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "footer", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return footer
        }
    }
}
```

3. Result in simulator:

[image]

4. **Important note**: I've used Xcode 7 beta 5 (Swift 2.0)

Comment: Confirmed working for Xcode 6.4. I found it strange that the **header** was being triggered even without `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` conformance.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**: Set the `footerReferenceSize`on your `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` greater than 0

**Option 2**: Implement the `collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection:)`
 function in you `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Comment: Weird thing was, **option 1** did not work. I had set `footerReferenceSize` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Option 1 will work as long as you instantiate `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, then set `footerReferenceSize`, then pass that to the initializer for UICollectionView.

Answer (score -2):

Drag and drop 
`CollectionReusableView`
 for both header and footer in 
`UICollectionViewController`
 from storyBoard and give identifier for each. The same process you drag and drop `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` and give cell identifier.
Good luck

Comment: By checking the box shown in my screenshot, `UICollectionReusableView` objects are automatically placed into the `collectionView` hierarchy.